# Selected Datetime From SQL Table in hh:mm:ss to datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatable

I want to selected Datetime from a SQL table to a datatable like "2015-09-14 13:39:34".
My SQL table datetime datatype was `datetime(27)`.

But when I selected, it came out like "09/15/2015 3:10 PM".

How can I get the time in seconds, like "dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss"?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify date like

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx) you have possible formats for `DateTime` in SQL Server but this will return date as string.

I'd format date time on application side to display it to user:

```
string dateFormatted = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I should be more clear probably. I meant to do date formatting on application side so this is C#.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking at this the wrong way, you should keep the date as a date object and only format when displaying to the user using the controls format property

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a format that is not a normal standard. In sqlserver 2008 you will have to [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CAST_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) a syntax like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(11), getdate(), 103) 
        + replace(convert(char(8), getdate(), 114), ':', '/')
```

In sqlserver 2012+ you can use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(FORMAT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

```
SELECT FORMAT( getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss')
```